# DataBound Pivot with ListBox - design-time sample data

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, listbox, pivot

On my MainPage is a pivot bound to a list of locations. Each location has a property 'RoomNumber' that is bound to the inner ListBox.

This is the XAML:

```
<controls:Pivot x:Name="mainPivot" ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}" Title="App-Title">
        <controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LocationName}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>

        <controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Rooms}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ListBoxItem>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding RoomNumber}" />
                            </ListBoxItem>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
             </DataTemplate>
        </controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
    </controls:Pivot>
```

At runtime this results in having a PivotItem for each location and all the corresponding RoomNumbers in the nested ListBox. Perfect!

But when I try to add some sample data at design time I can't get it to show data.
I added the Blend-namespace to the PhoneApplicationPage and a designtime-datacontext:

```
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DataContext="{d:DesignData SampleData/MainViewModelSampleData.xaml}"
```

The sample data contains some locations with nested rooms, but the rooms don't show up.
The pivot-headers are shown, so it cannot be wrong at all. But the inner ListBox is empty, so that I can't visually design the ListBoxItems.

First I thought it has something to do with the pivots itemindex bug not showing the first page. But setting the itemindex in xaml to 0 or 1 doesn't do the trick.

I also tried some different ways to bind the data, but nothing works. So after hours of trying and searching the web I hope someone has an idea.

some sidenotes:

- I don't know if it matters, but in the end I think I will use the SL-Toolkits LongListSelector instead of the ListBox
- Because it already works fine at runtime I'd prefer a XAML-only solution, because I'd prefer not to change my ViewModel just to get the designer working. But if there is no choice I will change the viewmodel nonetheless.

edit:
sorry, should have added the used sample data. here it is:

```
<local:MainViewModel 
    ... some namespaces ...
    >

    <local:MainViewModel.Locations>
        <PCSE:Location Id="1" LocationName="a name">
            <PCSE:Location.Rooms>
                <PCSE:Room Id="1" Date="10.08.2011" RoomNumber="1">
                </PCSE:Room>
                <PCSE:Room Id="2" Date="11.08.2011" RoomNumber="66">
                </PCSE:Room>
                <PCSE:Room Id="3" Date="12.08.2011" RoomNumber="45">
                </PCSE:Room>
            </PCSE:Location.Rooms>
        </PCSE:Location>
        ... some more locations ...
    </local:MainViewModel.Locations>

</local:MainViewModel>
```

This is shortened. There are more locations and the rooms have some child nodes. I also removed some attributes from the locations and also from the rooms to make it more readable.

FYI: there is no red underlined node/attribute, so I assume there are no typos.

Comment: How do you create your sample data? What's in it?

Comment: sorry, I have edited the question...
The xaml-file initially comes from the project template. But the data in it is manually written by me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it works now.

The problem is, I'm not sure what exactly fixed the problem. But here is what I have done:

- Since asking this question I have restructured the project. I didn't change the classes, the sample data and the xaml. But I moved all of it to a class library instead of the phone application.
- After creating the new class library I added the silverlight toolkit with NuGet, so I got a newer version of the toolkit than I was using before.
- In the constructor of the ViewModel I added this: `this.Locations = new ObservableCollection<Location>();`
  Without this line it reproducable doesn't work. But it doesn't work at all. Before the restructuring I saw the headers and only the content was missing. When I now remove this line, the headers are missing, too.

I assume it was the updated toolkit in combination with creating the ObservableCollection in the constructor. But I'm not sure